# How to solve merge conflicts without merging the target branch into my branch on a 3-branch base repository?

Tags: git, git-merge, git-branch, git-merge-conflict

I'm working on a project where we have the following branches:

- dev
- test
- main

The way we're creating feature branches is branching of `main` into `feature/<id>`. We then later create a PR from `feature/<id>` to `dev`. If everything is ok etc we proceed with `feature/<id>` to `test` and then to `main`.

The problem is that sometimes we have conflicts from `feature/<id>` to `dev`. We never want to merge `dev` into the feature branch (to avoid sending *all* dev code to test). So, to solve conflicts we're using Azure interface (which sucks) to solve the merge conflicts. By using this tool, it does not merge `dev` into the feature, it does exactly what we want which is `feature` -> `dev` (in some temporary state which keeps the PR open).

To do the same locally the only alternative we have found so far is to create a temporary branch from `dev`, merge the feature into this new branch and remake a PR with `temp`->`dev`.

Is there a better way to handle conflicts in this scenario?

Comment: Why don't you just do what azure does? Merge feature into dev.

Comment: dev is a protected branch

Comment: Actually what I do if there is a merge conflict `feature/<id>` to `dev` is merge `dev` into `feature/<id>` locally to resolve the conflict first. Can you do that?

Comment: If I do that it'd be tainting my feature branch. So, I can, but only if it's in a temp branch that I'll need to open a new PR for.

Comment: Ok well that's your opinion and you're entitled to it. I do this all the time and nothing gets "tainted" but whatever. I hardly see what difference the branch name is going to make in any case.

Comment: Are you saying that I can do that even if there are 100 other feature branches merged into dev and my changes will be carried over up to `main` without affecting the program integrity even if 95 PRs are not merged before mine? Sorry if that is the case, I'm not an expert with git, just want to understand how it works.

Comment: Well the fact that you branch from main but merge that branch into dev seems nutty to me, especially if dev is protected in a way that prevents local conflict resolution. How many ways can we shoot ourselves in the foot?  But I don't see what difference a "temp branch" is going to make.

Comment: Why would your local merging practices be any different than on the remote? The practices are basically the same, but the tooling may be different.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a common problem, and by the way, the fact that you have 3 branches doesn't matter; only 2 branches are required for this issue to occur. If you use [the workflow that the Git project uses](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitworkflows) this can happen often with just `next` and `main`. The way to minimize the problem is to periodically reset `next` to `main`, or in your case you could consider periodically resetting both `dev` and `test` to `main`, to remove all the previous old code that never made its way into `main`.

Between resets though, I can only think of 3 good options (2 of which you already mentioned):

1. Resolve the conflicts in the online tool.
2. > To do the same locally the only alternative we have found so far is to create a temporary branch from dev, merge the feature into this new branch and remake a PR with temp->dev.

Making the temp branch is probably the most common way to go. It's slightly annoying because you have to maintain two branches from then on until you promote your branch or `dev` gets reset. A secondary annoyance is if you didn't notice you had conflicts until after you created the PR from feature into `dev`, you have to abandon that PR and create a new one for the temp branch, which leads to a possible 3rd option, though I only recommend this if you're comfortable with interactive rebase:

3. Squash merge `dev` into your working feature branch to resolve conflicts. Essentially you'll merge `dev` into your branch locally, but with a squash, and make the commit message something like, "delete-me: Squash merge in dev".

Note you are *tainting* your branch here, but this makes it easier to remove the merges later when you're ready to promote your branch. Once you're ready to promote, which in your case is `test`, you would interactive rebase and drop all those "delete-me" commits.

**Side Note:** I can't tell for sure from your description, but if you merge feature branches into `test`, and then separately merge those feature branches into `main` later, then it's possible you'll have the same problem on `test` and you'll need to repeat the process before going into `main`. (The alternative would be for `test` when ready, to be merged into `main`, and if you do that you shouldn't have this issue. If you merge feature branches separately, then you'll probably want to periodically reset `test` as well.)

**Tip:** Don't merge `dev` into your feature branch with a regular merge. Either maintain two branches or use squash merge. Come promotion time you don't want to deal with manually cherry-picking multiple commits which are spread out across your branch.

**What I do:** I used to switch between #2 and #3, but nowadays I mostly do something else which could possibly be **Option #4**: I branch off of `dev` first, add some commits, merge into `dev`, add more commits, merge into `dev`, etc. While I'm doing this I don't rewrite any commits on my branch; I only add new ones. If I manage to do this without any conflicts on `dev`, then when I'm ready to promote, I rewrite my branch to a few good commits that I'm happy with, and then I rebase it (with `--onto`) to the new target branch. If during that process I had conflicts and I could no longer simply add new commits to my branch, that's when I decide to go with #2 or #3.