# How to handle git conflict in this scenario

Tags: git, github, git-merge, merge-conflict-resolution

In our Deployment process, the Dev would create a feature branch from the main. Add their changes and when ready to be merged to lower env branches like QA or UAT, they will create pull requests. When UAT is done then that branch will migrate to production.

We use Github actions. When a PR is raised the deployment validation will be done, once that passes then it goes to the reviewer for review and the deployment triggers when a branch is merged to QA or UAT.

The problem starts with a pull request to QA or UAT which has branch conflicts. If we try to resolve the conflict then QA/UAT branch gets merged with the feature branch which we don't want because then we will have all other changes deployed on UAT in the Feature branch.

How to handle such a scenario where the conflict should be resolved without merging the UAT branch with the feature branch?

There are 2 options which we do and both I guess is not a recommended approach.

1. Add the conflict part in the target branch, for instance if the PR is for UAT branch then we will directly go in that file on UAT branch and fix it. This way we are resolving the conflict and also making sure the UAT branch changes are not getting merged in the Dev feature branch.
2. We delete the UAT or QA branch and recreate a new one from main/master. This way there is no conflict issue.

Comment: This is either a dup, or extremely related, to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75150080/184546).

Comment: By the way, your option #2 is a good one to do periodically. Maybe not so often that people haven't finished testing, but the more often you can do it without upsetting people, the better.

Comment: The other post is super helpful. Its same kind of problem which I have. Thanks for sharing.

Comment: In general (unrelated to git, even, this is an issue for ANY RCS), if there's a conflict, the dev who authored the feature branch should resolve the conflicts. A smart dev might merge `main` into their feature branch, resolve conflicts, then merge their updated branch into `testing`, so other devs won't have to resolve the same conflicts.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the Git CLI, you can check out the UAT branch and then run `git merge <feature-branch>`. You will then be able to fix the merge conflicts and create a new commit containing those changes on the UAT branch. Your feature branch won't be affected at all.

Comment: I missed an important part in my post. We use Github actions and the deployment triggers when a branch is merged to QA or UAT.
So if I merge using CLI the actions wont trigger.

Comment: You can push the branch up to Github to trigger the action.

Comment: How? Can you please explain?

Comment: By using `git push`.

Comment: @DMalan git push will not work if you have protected branches